# Moving sheets with VBA codes and buttons to a new Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet with macros and buttons. I want to copy that worksheet to other workbooks so that the macros can be used with the data in the new workbook.

My problem is that when I copy a sheet into a new workbook, the macros come with it, but the button on the sheet still points to the macros in the original workbook. You have to right mouse click "Assign Macro" and choose the macro in the current workbook.

Is there a property setting that tells the button in Excel to use the macro in the new workbook instead of the old workbook?

Comment: Please post the complete code that is giving you trouble. State where is that code located.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I pulled from TheSpreadsheetGuru. I modified it to accept a sheet object so you can run it against any sheet you have a handle on.

```
Public Sub FixCopiedButtonMacroLinks(ByVal theSheet As Worksheet)
    ' UPDATED: by HackSlash to accept a worksheet parameter.
    'PURPOSE: Remove an external workbook reference from all shapes triggering macros
    'Source: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim control As Shape
    Dim MacroLink As String
    Dim SplitLink As Variant
    Dim NewLink As String

    'Loop through each shape in worksheet
    For Each control In theSheet.Shapes

        'Grab current macro link (if available)
        MacroLink = control.OnAction

        'Determine if shape was linking to a macro
        If MacroLink <> vbNullString And InStr(MacroLink, "!") <> 0 Then
            'Split Macro Link at the exclaimation mark (store in Array)
            SplitLink = Split(MacroLink, "!")

            'Pull text occurring after exclaimation mark
            NewLink = SplitLink(1)

            'Remove any straggling apostrophes from workbook name
            If Right(NewLink, 1) = "'" Then
                NewLink = Left(NewLink, Len(NewLink) - 1)
            End If

            'Apply New Link
            control.OnAction = NewLink
        End If
    Next control
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a line in your macro that re-assigns the control to the macro in its own workbook instead of the originating workbook.

What you can do is just record the act of assigning the macro, for example:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
Selection.OnAction = "Macro1"
```

Then get rid of the pesky "select" stuff:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).OnAction = "Macro1"
```

And there you have it.  Of course the button and macro names with vary depending on your workbook, but it will be close to that.

Comment: I'm a newbie, so I'm not following.  Where would this macro be stored and how would it be activated?

Comment: As Sancho states in his answer, use Alt+F11 to open your IDE where the macros are stored.  Macros can be stored in sheets or modules, if your macros are supposed to follow the copied sheets then they need to be within the sheets themselves so that when the sheets are copied over the macro follows.  Congratulations on your progress!  Macro editing is a very important step in your "Excel Evolution".

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat vague. I will then guess.

You have to:

1. Make sure that the `Sub`s to be run are actually contained in the `Worksheet` to be copied. Press Alt+F11 to open the VB Editor, and you will see on the left the Sheet and other modules.
2. Inspect the code, and make sure all references to macros are not prefixed with any Sheet/Workbook name.